# Index on exists condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, exists

Suppose you have a simple one-to-many (master-detail) schema, with indices:

```
create table master (
    id serial primary key,
    foo integer not null
);

create index master_foo on master (foo);

create table detail (
    id serial primary key,
    master_id integer not null references master (id),
    bar integer not null
);

create index detail_master_id on detail (master_id);
create index detail_bar on detail (bar);
create index detail_master_id_bar on detail (master_id, bar);
```

And suppose you need to run a query on the master table, with some condition in OR on the existence of specific details (33 and 44 of course can be arbitrary values, not known beforehand):

```
select *
from master
where foo = 33
or exists (
    select 1
    from detail
    where detail.master_id = master.id
    and bar = 44
);
```

This query is using any of the available indices on detail, but ***none on master!***

```
Seq Scan on master  (cost=0.00..18508.10 rows=1136 width=8)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Filter: ((foo = 33) OR (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Index Only Scan using detail_master_id_bar on detail  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=0)
          Index Cond: ((master_id = master.id) AND (bar = 44))
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on detail detail_1  (cost=4.23..14.79 rows=10 width=4)
          Recheck Cond: (bar = 44)
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on detail_bar  (cost=0.00..4.23 rows=10 width=0)
                Index Cond: (bar = 44)
```

In the real world case, master is a huge table. How can I rearrange this query (or the data structure itself, with triggers?) in order not to have to perform a full scan on master, which I need to avoid?

Comment: Is there an index on master(foo)? I don't see it... Also you should make your test cases large enough. If the table is tiny, postgres will just seq scan it and not bother with the index.

Comment: some left join doesn't work?

Comment: @bobflux you can see the index on master (foo) right below create table master. Also I'm using explain without analyze, so the real world data is not taken into account.

Comment: Apparently the OR messes things up. If you use "select from master where foo=... UNION select from master where exists" it is fast.

Comment: @Tobia does it speed things up a bit? `explain select * from master, detail
where (detail.master_id = master.id and detail.bar = 44) or foo = 33;` or even `explain select master.* from master
join detail on detail.master_id = master.id and detail.bar = 44
union all select master.* from master where foo = 33;`

Answer (score 1):

Either split it into two queries or at least try to avoid the `OR` with the subquery. I would go with:

```
explain analyse select master.* from master
join detail on detail.master_id = master.id and detail.bar = 44
union all
select master.* from master where foo = 33;

                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append  (cost=0.57..24.95 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.027..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..16.61 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using detail_bar on detail  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (bar = 44)
         ->  Index Scan using master_pkey on master  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)
               Index Cond: (id = detail.master_id)
   ->  Index Scan using master_foo on master master_1  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (foo = 33)
 Planning Time: 1.134 ms
 Execution Time: 0.085 ms
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f938f4ed0cbe541374866ab61fad4e74)